# How to Check Whether a Computer is Locked or not Using Java JNI

Tags: java, windows, macos, ubuntu, java-native-interface

I am trying to check whether a computer is locked or not using Java, but I am not getting how to do it. So is there any way to do this? I am running on Ubuntu, and I want to do it for Ubuntu, Windows and Mac.

Comment: its the way form the terminal and i am not looking for that bady.. okey so its not duplicate. check it again

Comment: The answer in the thread shows a possibility how to do it for windows and I don't think there is a general approach to this, so you'd have to do it for each OS using JNI to call native functions to retrieve the state.

Comment: can u give example i need example not just explanation..

Comment: That's why I only commented and didn't answer. Maybe someone has done it before and can give you an answer but I can't without research right now.